# Make the last column in a JavaFX TableView take the remaining space

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

How do I make the last column in a JavaFX TableView take the remaining space.

I have tried `table.setColumnResizePolicy(TableView.CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY);` but this makes the column sizes equal. I want only the last column to grow when the window width increases.

Comment: You may setMaxWidth for previous tableColumns.

Answer (score 1):

If you want all the columns in your tableview to fill up the window space available to the tableview AND be dynamically resized to adjust to changing the size of the window, then you need to bind the column properties to the tableview's width.

For example, say I have 5 columns in a tableview.  I want them to always be a fixed percentage of the available width (so that when the window is resized, the proportions of the columns remain constant).  You can easily form your own column sizing rules using the same property binding idiom (eg.  I want the last column to take all the remaining space).

In the initialize() method of the controller that has my TableView control, I could do the following:

```
void initialize() {


    // Initialize your logic here: all @FXML variables will have been injected
    :
    :
    // TableView column control variables are prefixed with "tco"
    tcoLast.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Client.Expand, String>("lastName"));
    tcoFirst.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Client.Expand, String>("firstName"));
    tcoDoB.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Client.Expand, Integer>("doB"));
    tcoMRN.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Client.Expand, String>("defMRN"));
    tcoGen.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Client.Expand, String>("gender"));

    // Cell factories for rendering certain columns in the TableView
    tcoLast.setCellFactory(new ClientNameTableCellFactory());
    tcoFirst.setCellFactory(new ClientNameTableCellFactory());
    tcoDoB.setCellFactory(new ClientDoBTableCellFactory());

    // Set fixed column widths that resize automatically
    // Values are weighted to be a fraction of a total of 41 (arbitrary)        
    tcoLast.prefWidthProperty().bind(tbvMatches.widthProperty().multiply(11.0/41.0));
    tcoFirst.prefWidthProperty().bind(tbvMatches.widthProperty().multiply(11.0/41.0));
    tcoDoB.prefWidthProperty().bind(tbvMatches.widthProperty().multiply(8.0/41.0));
    tcoMRN.prefWidthProperty().bind(tbvMatches.widthProperty().multiply(8.0/41.0));
    tcoGen.prefWidthProperty().bind(tbvMatches.widthProperty().multiply(2.0/41.0));
    :
    :
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my FXML based solution:

```
<TableView fx:id="log">
 <columns>
  <TableColumn fx:id="logDir"  maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="30.0"  prefWidth="50.0"  sortable="false" text="Dir" />
  <TableColumn fx:id="logTime" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="50.0"  prefWidth="70.0"  sortable="false" text="Time" />
  <TableColumn fx:id="logHex"  maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="0.0"   prefWidth="100.0" sortable="false" text="Hex" />
  <TableColumn fx:id="logDesc" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="100.0" 
               prefWidth="${log.width-logDir.width-logTime.Width-logHex.width}" sortable="false" text="Description" />
 </columns>
</TableView>
```

Notes:

- maxWidth is MAX_VALUE
- minWidth and prefWidth to sensible values to allow user resize
- prefWidth of the last column is bound to width of the TableView minus sum of widths of the other columns

Answer (score 0):

My simple solution is to overestimate the preferred width of the last column.

```
TableColumn<KeyNode, String> columnA = new TableColumn<>();
columnA.setPrefWidth(100);
TableColumn<KeyNode, String> columnB = new TableColumn<>();
columnB.setPrefWidth(100);
TableColumn<KeyNode, String> columnC = new TableColumn<>();
columnC.setPrefWidth(100);
:
TableColumn<KeyNode, String> columnZ = new TableColumn<>();
columnZ.setPrefWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

One can do better solutions with binding on the widths, and I thought there was a possibility to let the last column fill out (I did not see the latter mentioned here).

Comment: But do you see the Caption of that Column?

Comment: The **preferred width** not is the actual set (lower) width, so it should pose no problem. Left aligning the last headers should not be needed.